# Update chosen XML element but don't change the rest of the file in MSBuild

Tags: xml, xpath, msbuild

I am trying to create an `MSBuild` project file in order to build an application. One of the steps in this process is to create .exe file. I have decided to use `launch4j` for it. `Launch4j` needs an XML configuration file in order to work and it is possible to pass that through command line.

I am having a problem when I try to update an element in the configuration file. It seemd to be simple and clear so I have decided to use `MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Xml.XmlFile` task for this job.

My target which executes `XmlFile` task

```
<Target Name="Java">
    <Error Condition="!Exists('$(GitLocation)git.exe')"  Text="Git is not installed" ContinueOnError="false"/>

    <!-- create directory if it does not exist and clone project from the repository -->
    <Exec Command='mkdir $(RepositoryLocation) %26 "$(GitLocation)git.exe" clone $(GitRemoteLocation) $(RepositoryLocation)'
          ContinueOnError="false"
          WorkingDirectory="."
          ConsoleToMSBuild="true"
          Condition="!Exists('$(RepositoryLocation)')"/>

    <!-- if the folder already exists, try to update -->
    <Exec Command='"$(GitLocation)git.exe" pull origin $(branch)'
          ContinueOnError='false'
          WorkingDirectory='$(RepositoryLocation)' />

    <SetEnvironmentVariableTask Name="JAVA_HOME" Value="$(JAVA_PATH)" Condition="Exists('$(JAVA_PATH)')"/>

    <!-- build Production Manager -->
    <Exec Command='"$(Maven)" clean install -DskipTests=true'
          ContinueOnError='false'
          WorkingDirectory='$(RepositoryLocation)$(ProductionManager)' />

    <!-- copy .jar file to the setup location -->
    <Copy SourceFiles='$(RepositoryLocation)$(ProductionManager)\target\$(ProductionManagerOutput)'
          DestinationFolder='$(RepositoryLocation)$(ProductionManagerSetup)' />

    <!-- copy all libraries to the setup location -->
    <Copy 
      SourceFiles='@(ProductionManagerFiles)'
      DestinationFiles="@(ProductionManagerFiles -> '$(RepositoryLocation)$(ProductionManagerSetup)\lib\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />

    <!-- update jar and outfile elements of launch4jconfig-->
    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Xml.XmlFile TaskAction="UpdateElement" File="$(RepositoryLocation)$(Launch4jConfigPath)" XPath="/launch4jConfig/jar" InnerText="$(RepositoryLocation)$(ProductionManagerSetup)$(ProductionManagerOutput)"/>
    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Xml.XmlFile TaskAction="UpdateElement" File="$(RepositoryLocation)$(Launch4jConfigPath)" XPath="/launch4jConfig/outfile" InnerText="$(RepositoryLocation)$(ProductionManagerSetup)$(ProductionManagerExe)"/>

    <!-- execute launch4j and create .exe file-->
    <!--<Exec Command='"$(Launch4j)launch4jc.exe" $(RepositoryLocation)$(Launch4jConfigPath)'
          ContinueOnError='false'
          WorkingDirectory='$(RepositoryLocation)$(ProductionManagerSetup)' />-->
  </Target>
```

It works good and it really updates the selected element but it changes the xml file completely.
E.g.
Config.xml -> before parsing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <headerType>gui</headerType>
    <jar>...</jar>
    <outfile>...</outfile>
    ...
    <manifest></manifest>

    <icon></icon>
    ...
</config>
```

Config.xml -> after parsing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <headerType>gui</headerType>
    <jar>...</jar>
    <outfile>...</outfile>
    ...
    <manifest>
    </manifest>

    <icon>
    </icon>
    ...
</config>
```

As you can see open and close tags are not on the same line after parsing and I causes an exception

`launch4j: Manifest doesn't exist.` and by that I am not able to create .exe file

My question, would it be somehow possible to update only choosen elements and the rest of it leave like in the original file?

Is there any other solution or workaround for this?

Thanx in advance

Comment: I am quite surprised it changes the XML completely. Do you use a recent version of the ExtensionPack? If you check the source (it is open source) you can find that it uses `XmlDocument.Save()`, and that it only updates the internal value of any elements found by your xpath. Other elements are left untouched. You may try to debug into the `MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Xml.TrySave` function and see what happens. Perhaps on a later stage something "touches" the file by another task?

Comment: Hello and first of all, thx for replying! I have downloaded MSBuild Tools 2013 from the [homepage](http://www.microsoft.com/de-de/download/details.aspx?id=40760) and installed it. The version I am using is 4.0 and the only xml tasks I have in this ExpansionPack are `XmlFile` and `XmlTask`. `TrySave` task I haven't found. Speaking about the sources I have found [this](https://github.com/mikefourie/MSBuildExtensionPack) but there I also haven't found anything about XmlTasks... Is the 4.0 the last version of it? Which one have you used? Thx

Comment: The last version is of March 2015, it is version 4.0.11, you can find them here; http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/. `TrySave` is not a task, it is a method inside the DLL which you can view using [.NET Reflector](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) or similar .NET disassembly tools. The MSBuild extension pack is open source, so you can run the solution and use a simple test. However, I sincerely doubt that the XmlDocument used internally adds whitespace text nodes, hence my guess that it is from another part of your code.

Comment: Yes I have found it and I also use the latest version. Interesting because these two XmlFile tasks were the last which I have executed in the script. I have uploaded my target code above. Can you please throw a look and see If you could find something unusual? thx

Answer (score 0):

After I have been searching for a solution, I have come to an idea to create my own `XML` parser. So I have added one new `UsingTask` tag to my `MSBuild` script and It looks like this

```
<UsingTask
    TaskName="UpdateXmlTask"
    TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory"
    AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v$(MSBuildToolsVersion).dll">

        <ParameterGroup>
            <file ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
            <path ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
            <value ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
        </ParameterGroup>

        <Task>
            <Reference Include="System.Xml"/>
            <Using Namespace="System" />
            <Using Namespace="System.Xml" />
            <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
                <![CDATA[
            var doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
            doc.Load(file);
            var node = doc.SelectSingleNode(path);
            node.InnerText = value;
            var settings = new XmlWriterSettings()
            {
                Indent = true,
                NewLineChars = Environment.NewLine,
                NewLineOnAttributes = false,
                NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.None
            };
            var writer = XmlWriter.Create(file, settings);
            doc.Save(writer);
            writer.Close();
      ]]>
            </Code>
        </Task>
    </UsingTask>
```

If you also want to remove all whitespaces, just remove `doc.PreserveWhitespace = true` or change it to `false`

You can use this task as follows

```
<UpdateXmlTask 
        file="path to the file" 
        path="path to the xml element, using xpath"
        value="new value" />
```